# email validation function not working with element[x] in javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, validation, email, function

I added this validate email function here at the top, and i don't know how to make it ref. element[6] which is the email field in the form, and I'm not sure what the

```
return re.test(email);
```

statement is all about
here is the full script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}   


function validation(form) {
  if(form.elements[3].value == '' ) {
      alert('Please enter your first name');
      form.first_name.focus();
      return false;
  }

  if(form.elements[4].value == '') {
      alert('Please enter your last name');
      form.last_name.focus();
      return false;
  }

  if(form.elements[6].value == '') {
      alert('Please enter your email address');
      form.email.focus();
      return false;

  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " is a valid email address :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + "is not a valid email address :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
    return false;
  }

  if(form.elements[7].value == '') {
      alert('Please enter your telephone number');
      form.phone.focus();
      return false;
  }

  if(form.elements[17].value == '') {
      alert('Please let us know what you are most interested in');
      form.phone.focus();
      return false;
  }

  if(form.elements[18].value == '') {
      alert('Please enter the area you are most interested in');
      form.phone.focus();
      return false;
  }

  if(form.elements[20].value == '') {
      alert('Please enter the low end of your budget');
      form.phone.focus();
      return false;
  }

  if(form.elements[21].value == '') {
      alert('Please enter the high end of your budget');
      form.phone.focus();
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function:

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

has a regex object (`re`), the regex object uses the `test` function to test if the email passed into the function validates according to the regex. the `test` function returns `true` if it validates as an email and `false` if it doesnt.

you can use it like this:

```
if(!validateEmail(form.elements[6].value)) {
  alert('Please enter a valid email address');
  form.email.focus();
  return false;
}
```

The test function is native to regex objects, meaning your browser will know what to do with it (specs for the test function: [developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/) )

Comment: i don't see a test function however... :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript/46181#46181

Comment: @DarekBridges [Regex.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is a javascript function, you have it.

Comment: @DarekBridges the test function is native to regex objects, meaning your browser will know what to do with it (specs for the test function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Answer (score 0):

Inside you `validation()` function variable `email` that is being passed to `validateEmail` is pretty much undefined.

You should either:

```
validateEmail(form.email.value);
```

OR

```
validateEmail($('#email').val()); // considering that `email` field has id="email"
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

`form.elements` was the way you selected DOM elements in 1996. You should be using `document.getElementById` instead:

```
var resultElement = $("#result");
var emailVal = document.getElementById('emailBoxId').value;
if (validateEmail(emailVal )) {
    resultElement
      .text(emailVal + " is a valid email address :)")
      .css("color", "green");
} else {
    resultElement
      .text(emailVal + "is not a valid email address :(")
      .css("color", "red");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: muwhahah... i was forced to use `form.elements` because i am not in control of my id's they are auto generated by a database :) and the database prefaces almost all of the id's with `00`

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `email` and set its value to `form.elements[6].value`

e.g.

```
function validation(form) {
  if(form.elements[3].value == '' ) {
    alert('Please enter your first name');
    form.first_name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  //...
  var email = form.elements[6].value
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " is a valid email address :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + "is not a valid email address :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
    return false;
  }
 //...
}
```